# How to add route without via / specifying the next hop IP?

Tags: linux, networking, iproute

I know that I can add route using

`ip route add default via 5.5.5.5 dev eth1 table 200`

But what if `eth1` is a wireless interface getting its IP via DHCP because I don't know the AP's IP before hand? What command options should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much you can't.

One of the pieces of information that you get from the reply to a DHCP request is the address of (usually 1) gateway. You use this information to fill in the value that you are showing as `5.5.5.5`. So the flow would be that you join the wireless network, you send out a DHCP request as a broadcast, you get a replay that you use to configure the network interface, in particular the IP address, and also the routing table.

A different approach is to use a routing protocol on your LAN. These will broadcast or multicast out information about routes. You would run a daemon on your system which would listen to these and update the kernel routing table.

You question needs there to be 2 or more routes from your computer, either say an ethernet and wifi or 2 wifi base stations on the same network, to make much sense. Usually you would only have one base station and add the route commands on that rather than on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

To recover the value of the default gateway (if it was provided via DHCP) you could go to the place where your DHCP client saves its leases, read the one for your interface, find the option `routers` and use its value.

The details depend on the DHCP client you are using, the lease could be in a `.lease` text file in `/var/lib/NetworkManager` or in a binary `.lease` file in `/var/lib/dhcpcd5/` that you can dump with `dhcpcd5 --dumplease your_interface` or ... you'll have to find out for your system.